# Const Variable in "Type"-Statement vba

Tags: vba, excel, constants, ms-word

I want to sum up my Const Variables in a VBA Makro like this:

```
Private Type Company
   Public Const CompanyNameColumns As String = "14"
   Public Const CompanyNameStartRow As Integer = 5
Type End
```

I can't run this code. 
I think the problem is, that there is no possibility of defining a Const within a Type Statement.
Has anybody a workaround for that?

Comment: Well.... I can definitely say that [the documentation for user defined types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278633(v=office.15).aspx) is incredibly unhelpful....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, it took me a second, but then it smacked me like a ton of bricks what's going on here.

**TL;DR**: You can't assign values during definition of a type, but there is a proper way to do what you're trying to do.

The reason you can't assign to it is because you're defining a *type*. I know that sounds cyclical and redundant, but that's exactly what is going on. You're trying to assign values in a place that is meant to define a *data structure*. That's all a UDT does. It defines a structure. It makes no sense to assign values to a structure.

As you've found, one solution is to create a new module and store your constants there.

**Constants.bas**

```
Public Const CompanyNameColumns As String = "14"
Public Const CompanyNameStartRow As Integer = 5
```

Which then gets called like this...

```
Constants.CompanyNameColumns
Constants.StartNameRow
```

And this is fine, but runs the risk of becoming a catch all. It would be much better to move these into a class module along with the logic they relate to. That way all of the related logic and data are in one place instead of scattered about multiple *.bas files in your project.

If you're going the class route, but the classes only hold this data structure, without any real state, you might want to consider [making them global default instances](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59215/41243). This is similar to what is known as "static" classes in other languages.

Comment: I needed two Constant "Structures" and now I just moved them into 2 Class Modules (to be honest I didn't know the difference between a Module and a Class Module because I normally code in vb.net)

Thank you for explaining why the hole thing didn't work

Comment: I added some extra information. You're very welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid, that the link to the implementation of static classes in VBA in the Post you linked doesn't work :/

Comment: It absolutely does work @greece57. I do it all the time for various reasons. If you're having trouble with it, I suggest creating a new question on that topic.

Comment: I mean [this link](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/making-vba-classes-static-and-calling-members-without-initialization/) @RubberDuck:

Comment: Oh. I'll make sure to let vba4all know that. But there are instructions for implementation in the CR link I posted.

Comment: @greece57 you can think of a VBA *Standard Module* (.bas) as a VB.NET *Shared Class*, if it's any help.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this Problem now by just defining a new Module. Named it Company and put the Consts in there!

Comment: I mostly code vb.net Code and when I tried to define a class it wasn't possible. Now i know why :D
Didn't know that you can add Class Moduls. Thanks!

Comment: Meehow, here's another one... please delete this comment as it's linking through to pharma scam.  Save the URL though and you can grab the legit copy in the Wayback Machine.  For now, readers are advised to avoid clicking.